# Validate not working for dialog populated with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, dialog, jquery-validate

I have tried countless suggestions from here and elsewhere but nothing works so please can anyone cast light on why my code is failing.

The html created by the Ajax call is (the content of the selects is hidden but all are correctly closed)

```
<div id="adc" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block;   width: auto; min-height: 46px; max-height: none; height: auto;">
You must complete fields marked *.
<br>
<br>
<form id="addcont" ;="" autocomplete="off" name="addcont">
    <fieldset>
        Type of contractor/supplier:
        <select id="otype" name="org_type">
            <div id="orgnm" class="hideonload" style="display: block;">
                * Full name of organisation:
                <input id="full_name" class="required" type="text" size="50" value="" name="full_name">
                <br>
                <span id="flagger"></span>
                <input type="hidden" value="test" name="dbextn">
                <input type="hidden" value="1" name="princip">
                *Business Group:
                <br>
                <select id="bgroup" name="busn_group">
                    <br>
                    <div id="clasdiv" class="hideonload" style="display: block;">
                        * Business Class:
                        <select id="bclass" name="busn_clas">
                        </div>
                        <div id="typediv" class="hideonload" style="display: block;">
                            <br>
                            <div id="locat" class="hideonload" style="display: block;">
                                The location you add MUST be that of the master contact address.
                                <br>
                                <table id="loc-add">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="100px">
                                                <strong>Principal address</strong>
                                                :
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="500px">
                                                <select id="loc_type" name="loc_type">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Location name:</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input id="locat_name" type="text" placeholder="You must give the location a name" size="40" value="" name="locat_name">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>*Address line1:</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input id="address1" class="required" type="text" size="40" value="" name="address1">
                                                    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="status">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Address line2:</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input id="address2" type="text" size="40" value="" name="address2">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>*Town :</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input id="town" class="required" type="text" size="40" value="" name="town">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>*Postcode:</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input id="postcode" class="required" type="text" size="10" value="" name="postcode">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>County:</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <select name="county">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td> Country:</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select id="country" name="country">
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>*Phone no:</td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input id="phone" class="required" type="text" size="15" value="" name="phone">
                                                            <br>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            <br>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

I can see from Firebug that the core libraries including the validator is being loaded.

My jquery script is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.nextbut').hide();
$(document).on('click','a.addcontr', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var organid=$('#basinf').attr("parn");
    var usrd =  $('#basinf').attr("pare");
    var dbextn = $('#basinf').attr("dbextn");
    var parf =  $('#basinf').attr("parf");
    var $tag = $("<div id='adc'><img src='images/loading.gif'></div>");
    $.post("ajax/createContractor.php",
    {organid: organid, dbextn: dbextn, parf: parf},
    function(data) {
        $tag.html(data).dialog({autoOpen: false, title: "Adding a contractor",
            width: 540,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Add Contractor" : function() { $('#addcont').validate({debug: true ,
                    rules:{
                        full_name: "required",
                        locat_name: "required",
                        address1:"required",
                        town:"required",
                        postcode:"required"
                    },
                    messages: {
                        full_name: " Enter name of organisation",
                        locat_name: " Enter location name",
                        address1: " Enter address",
                        town: " Enter town or city",
                    postcode: " Enter postcode"}, 
                    submitHandler:function(){$.post("ajax/insContractor.php",$('#addcont').serialize(),function(data){ 
                        $( '#adc' ).dialog( "close" );});}
                });

                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: function() {$('#addcont').remove();
                $('#adc').remove();
            }}).dialog('open'); 

    });$('#addcont').validate();
});
});
```

I have tried putting the validate call everywhere, including via an open:

```
function(event, ui){$('#addcont').validate();}, just after modal: true,
```

Comment: Create a jsFiddle, otherwise, I don't think very many people are going to want to dig into such a complex problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're calling `$('#addcont').validate(...)` twice.  You **cannot** call it multiple times.

- The `.validate()` method is **only for initializing** the plugin on your form.  The `.validate()` method is where you'd put your options.  You cannot call it more than once, so you cannot add, over-ride, or remove your options by calling it again.  Subsequent calls are ignored.
- When you call `.validate()` the form's HTML **must** already exist.  In most cases, it's called within a DOM ready event handler.  In cases where forms are dynamically created, it's called immediately after the HTML for the form is created.

Otherwise, I'll rely on you to construct a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue so that we have something to inspect and troubleshoot.

1. Trigger your ajax to create the form within the dialog.
2. After the HTML is fully constructed, then call the `.validate()` method along with options.

Looking at your code again, you need to totally remove the `.validate()` method inside of your `buttons:` option.  Since the validate plugin automatically captures the submit button, you would not need to do anything special.

Simply copy the validate rules and options from your deleted `.validate()` into the `.validate()` method at the end.

Comment: I did try moving it as you suggested but that was a blind alley and I did look at building a jsfiddle, created an account etc but found it totally too confusing as a newbie to it to replicate the ajax-delivery of the dialog and then validating. So I kept hunting and trying and days passed ....

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of suggestions about creating forms on the fly and shifting the dialog within the DOM with parent() and appendTo() but in the end I went back to the [plugin page](http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validate.form) and decided to leave the validation declaration and triggering within the dialog button but doing it programmatically.

I set up a variable with the form id to be checked, then an if statement to send the form if the validation succeeded. Wherever it exists within the DOM this works somehow, so one happy bunny. At least I can understand what is going on!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click','a.addcontr', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var organid=$('#basinf').attr("parn");
    var usrd =  $('#basinf').attr("pare");
    var dbextn = $('#basinf').attr("dbextn");
    var parf =  $('#basinf').attr("parf");
    var $tag = $("<div id='adc'><img src='images/loading.gif'></div>");
    $.post("ajax/createContractor.php",
    {organid: organid, dbextn: dbextn, parf: parf},
    function(data) {
        $tag.html(data).dialog({
            autoOpen: false, title: "Adding a contractor",
            width: 540,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Add Contractor" : function() {  
                    var validator=$('#addcont').validate({
                        rules:{
                            full_name: "required",
                            locat_name: "required",
                            address1:"required",
                            town:"required",
                            postcode:"required"
                        },
                        messages: {
                            full_name: " Enter name of organisation",
                            locat_name: " Enter location name",
                            address1: " Enter address",
                            town: " Enter town or city",
                        postcode: " Enter postcode"}
                    });
                    if(validator.form()){$.post("ajax/insContractor.php",$('#addcont').serialize(),function(data){ 
                        $( '#adc' ).dialog( "close" );
                    });}

                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: function() {$('#addcont').remove();
                $('#adc').remove();
            },
        }).dialog('open');  

    });
});
```

});